# Merge Tags: "hyperv" and "hyper-v"

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms

I suggest merging:

1. [hyperv](/questions/tagged/hyperv) (7 questions)
2. [hyper-v](/questions/tagged/hyper-v) (105 questions)

not sure which one is better hyper-v or hypervisor..

EDIT:  oversight on my part.. [hypervisor](/questions/tagged/hypervisor) should not be merged (see casperOne's) answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that [hyperv](/questions/tagged/hyperv) should be merged into [hyper-v](/questions/tagged/hyper-v), as [Hyper V refers to a specific Microsoft product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-V).

However, I don't believe that [hypervisor](/questions/tagged/hypervisor) should be merged with Hyper V, as a [hypervisor is a another term for a virtual machine manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervisor).